# Program to play piano on MIDI keyboard

Tags: windows, music, midi

audio MIDI keyboard.

The software it comes with is overcomplicated for me, so I use GarageBand on Mac.

Is there a simple free program for Windows - just to play realistic piano sound and that's it?

Answer (score 2):

This [open source virtualpiano project on Google code](http://code.google.com/p/virtualpiano/) might work.

"Realistic" piano sound might be a bit much for freeware, though. Most freebies just use whatever MIDI library is closest; GarageBand by contrast has some fairly high quality piano samples at its disposal.